# How to increase heap space in Google Go

Tags: go

I'm running the Go code from Rober Hundt's benchmark to compare performance of Go with the other languages. When I run the Go code from that benchmark (see http://code.google.com/p/multi-language-bench/source/browse/trunk/src/#src%2Fhavlak%2Fgo) I get an out of memory exception:

................runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 1048576-byte block (1270808576 in use)
throw: out of memory

My question is how I can increase Go's memory space. Is there some start-up parameter or some flag for the compiler that can be set accordingly? The Makefile file of the Go source doesn't reveal anything...

Thanks, Oliver

Answer (score 6):

If you share your OS version, if it is 32 vs 64 bits and your `go version` result, we can probably help you more.

- The 32-bit version of Go has known heap memory issues and is generally not used in production. Make sure you are using the 64-bit version of Go on a 64-bit platform.
- Go tip, the branch of go that will become Go 1.1 [has upgraded the maximum heap space from 8 GB to 128 GB](https://codereview.appspot.com/6828055/). The core Go developers I have spoken with recommend using Go tip for memory intensive production uses.
- Go on Windows is less used and thus less tested, this could be a bug. Go is much more tried and true on Linux ans to a lesser extent OS X.
- As peterSO mentioned, Robert Hundt's benchmark is flawed- read more here: [Profiling Go Programs](http://blog.golang.org/2011/06/profiling-go-programs.html)

Comment: I was using version 1.0.3 of the 32-bit version for Windows. Reason I thought I just needed to provide a compiler switch was that the respective Java code runs till completion without a problem. The stack size has to be increased with a jvm switch, but that's it. The Go program terminates prematurely. I will try on a Windows 64-box or on Linux using Go 1.1. Thanks for the hint. Seems that Go wants to allocate large contiguous memory blocks and that causes the problem as the jvm gc can live with a scattered memory space as it inevitably gets scattered and is optimized for that.

Comment: The ideal production environment for Go in my experience is Go tip on 64-bit Linux, but just getting on a 64-bit OS (Windows or Linux with 1.0.3 or tip) should fix the issues you are seeing.

Answer (score 4):

One can only wildly guess - for the lack of more details.

- If you're running a 32 bit Go version, try the 64 bit one instead and use the tip revision.
- If possible, use a *nix platform - it has IMO better memory management.

Answer (score 1):

Robert Hundt's benchmark is flawed. It's not a valid benchmark for Go. Read [Profiling Go Programs](http://blog.golang.org/2011/06/profiling-go-programs.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's interesting. Nevertheless, I remain thankful for any hint on how to specify a larger heap size :-)

Comment: @Oliver Plow: @jnml has already told you that you haven't provided sufficient details. You've ignored him. What version of Go are you using (output of `go version`)? What OS version are you using (output of `uname -a` or equivalent)? Do you have the problem with the code written by a Go expert (Russ Cox)?.

Answer (score 0):

For those that might be interested I sent a mail to mr. hundt himself asking whether there is some (undocumented) compiler switch with which the heap size could be adapted or parameterized somehow. This was because I first mistakenly assumed that such a switch must exist, but is not documented. And nobody hat replied to my post here seemed to know, either. I guess I was "too much inspired" here by how the jvm works ...

Anyway, he recommended to try different compilers (gcc based compiler, or the plan-9 based compiler) as one might work better than the other. Then try on a 64-bit machine, of course.

He also pointed my to some good article about Go's memory management: http://lwn.net/Articles/428100/

But no, there is no compiler switch to play around with memory settings.

Regards, Oliver